# how to use AND , OR in validation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am using Laravel and I have validaion like this

```
'color_amount' => 'sometimes',
       'color_amount_number.*' => 'required_with:color_amount,on',
       'specification_amount' => 'sometimes',
       'specification_amount_number.*' => 'required_with:specification_amount,on',
       'description' => 'required|min:10|max:4000',
       'amount' => ['required_unless:specification_amount,on,required_unless:color_amount,on','nullable',
       'regex:/^[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\-۰-۹ء-ي., ]+$/u','max:999999','min:0'
     ],
```

for 'amount' I want to use OR for example

> ***required_unless:specification_amount,on OR required_unless:color_amount,on***

how can I do this?

Comment: The pipe `|` works like AND  but there is no option for OR operator. Now you need to apply annual if-else to apply OR operations.

Answer (score 0):

A easier to read option would be to use callback:

```
    $rules = [
        'color_amount' => 'sometimes',
        'color_amount_number.*' => 'required_with:color_amount,on',
        'specification_amount' => 'sometimes',
        'specification_amount_number.*' => 'required_with:specification_amount,on',
        'description' => 'required|min:10|max:4000',
        'amount' => [
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                if (!$value && ($request->specification_amount == 'on' || $request->color_amount == 'on'))
                    $fail($attribute . ' is required.');
            },
            'required_unless:specification_amount,on,required_unless:color_amount,on',
            'nullable',
            'regex:/^[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\-۰-۹ء-ي., ]+$/u',
            'max:999999',
            'min:0'
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score -1):

use if and elseif and else
for example

```
$input = Input::only('account'); // dont use all(), ever
$rules = [
    'account' => 'required'
];
if (filter_var($input['account'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $rules['account'] .= '|exists:users,email';
}
else
{
    $rules['account'] .= '|exists:users,username';
}

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

Comment: `Input` class is not valid. It was removed [5 years ago](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2adbbbd91e9d6e2d569cc56f138b7273efe25651).